# Translate a List<TypeA> to List<TypeB>

Tags: reflection, extension-methods, servicestack

Understood the concept of [translate](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/BF-egdVm3M8/0DXLIeDoVJEJ). Used it in converting a DataModel Type to DTO type for presentation layer like this and worked fine.

```
objTypeB = objTypeA.TranslateTo<clsTypeB>();
```

Discrepancy between TypeA and TypeB was just the datatype of few properties and I converted them in the `Property Set` method.

But in the above implementation if the source is `List<TypeA>`, I have loop through each to translate to `TypeB` and add it another `List<TypeB>` instance. Is it possible to do something like this instead:

Assume `resultListA` is a `List<clsTypeA>`

```
var resultListB = resultListA.TranslateTo<List<clsTypeB>>();
```

I tried and does not seem to convert. I get a empty `resultListB`. Any easy approach to this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var resultListB = resultListA.ConvertAll(x => x.TranslateTo<clsTypeB>());
```

Comment: Thanks. 

This suggestion by Refactor worked too.

var resultListB = resultListA.Select(x => x.TranslateTo<clsTypeB>()).ToList();

Comment: Yes, but that's slower (which is why I didn't show it :) because it does an Enumerable projection before converting to a list.